# HU EV facing an open shove from sb with ~10bb

Tags: ev, heads-up

This is my first post, I'm looking to find out what the EV of calling this shove is. I've been reading Will Tipton's Expert HUNL book and I'm not really sure what to do when calculating the EV of calling and losing when my stack will not = 0 at the end of the hand.

This is what I did: EVfold = 2160, EVcall=((3000)(.52)+(1480)(.48))?

Even though villain has been aggressive from sb I put him on a range of 22+,A2s+,K2s+,Q9s+,JTs,T9s,98s,87s,76s,65s,54s,A2o+,K4o+,QTo+,JTo

In this case EVc>EVf so correct play is to call? Are the above calculations right or am I missing something? Should I even be calculating cEV or should I be calc. $EV?

NL (2 max) - Holdem - 2 players
Hand converted by PokerTracker 3: http://www.pokertracker.com

Villain is 81/77 from the sb through 50/2 hands

SB: 760.00

Hero (BB): 2,240.00

SB posts SB 40.00,

Hero posts BB 80.00

Pre Flop: (120.00) Hero has Qd Kc

SB raises to 760.00 and is all-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KQ offsuit apparently has about 48 - 50 % equity against that range (I calculated this using an equity calculator). So, given that the all-in was preflop, you essentially have a coin-flip. So it's very hard to determine if a call here would be +EV or -EV, especially because figuring out that range is always very hard. So the calculation of equity can (and usually is) a little off.

The thing is, given that SB has only about 10BB left, I would suggest that his range is even wider than you suggest (although not by much, since it's already pretty wide, it includes about 40 % of hands I think). Because of this, your equity might be a little higher, let's say about 55 %. In this case, it's clearly +EV (because pot odds = 1.23) and I think I would make the call if I were in that situation.